# Text with custom Persian font appears wrong in iOS9

Tags: fonts, ios9, persian

I have an app which is in Persian. I'm using a custom Persian font which was looking fine in iOS < 9 but after upgrading to iOS9 text appears wrong.
The letters are all in capital and they don't stick to each-other.
Please see the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use persian x series fonts.
For example if you are using 'B Yekan' font in your app, use 'X Yekan' instead.